# An integral with a decaying exponential with rational exponent

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, improper-integrals

I was working on some mathematical derivations while I faced this integral:

### $$\Large \int_0^\infty x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta x} e^{-\lambda \left[\frac{x^2}{2x+\eta}\right]}\ \mathrm{d}x \quad .$$

Does it have a closed-form solution? Any suggestions to simplify it?

Comment: Many differentiations under the integral sign may work. I'll check it later.

Comment: Not unless $\eta=0$.